# Angular 4 + Ionic: No provider for DocumentToken

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am building an Ionic project and am trying to create an API service to interact with my server. I created a module for my API in Angular:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ApiService } from "./api.service";
import { MarketItemsApi } from "./items/MarketItemsApi.service";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ApiService,
        MarketItemsApi
    ]
})
export class ApiModule {};
```

Which is implemented with a service for general RESTful endpoints:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  url: string = 'https://www.example.com/api/v1';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  get(endpoint: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + endpoint);
  }

  post(endpoint: string, body: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body);
  }

  put(endpoint: string, body: any) {
    return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body);
  }

  delete(endpoint: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + endpoint);
  }
}
```

And a service for the specific endpoint I want to hit:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from '../../../models/Item';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable ()
export class MarketItemsApi {
    constructor(private Api: ApiService) {}

    getMarketItems(marketItemsQuery: any): Observable<Item[]> {
        return this.Api.post('market-items', marketItemsQuery);
    }
}
```

I import the API module into my AppModule:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { TabsModule } from '../pages/tabs/tabs.module';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { TabsPageComponent } from "../pages/tabs/tabs.component";

import { ApiModule } from '../providers/api/api.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    TabsModule,
    ApiModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    TabsPageComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And then provide the specific API service to my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Item } from "../../models/Item";
import { MarketItemsApi } from '../../providers/api/items/MarketItemsApi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-market',
  templateUrl: 'market.html',
  providers: [ MarketItemsApi ]
})
export class MarketPageComponent implements OnInit {
  marketItems: Item[] = [];

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private MarketItems: MarketItemsApi) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.MarketItems
      .getMarketItems({})
      .subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
      })
  }
}
```

That component is contained in its own feature module:

```
import { MarketPageComponent } from "./market.component";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPageModule } from "ionic-angular";
import { MarketItemsApi } from '../../providers/api/items/MarketItemsApi.service'


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(MarketPageComponent)
    ],
    declarations: [
        MarketPageComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        MarketItemsApi
    ],
    exports: [
        MarketPageComponent
    ]
})
export class MarketPageModule {}
```

Which is again imported into a TabsModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TabsPageComponent } from "./tabs.component";
import { IonicPageModule } from "ionic-angular";
import { AboutPageModule } from "../about/about.module";
import { ContactPageModule } from "../contact/contact.module";
import { MarketPageModule } from "../market/market.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TabsPageComponent),
    AboutPageModule,
    ContactPageModule,
    MarketPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    TabsPageComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    TabsPageComponent
  ]
})
export class TabsModule { }
```

Which is then imported into the AppModule and used as an entryComponent.

Here's the error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken!
Error: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken!
```

After extensive searching, I can't find documentation for DocumentToken. Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

P.S. Here's my environment:

```
Ionic Framework: 3.6.1
Ionic App Scripts: 2.1.4
Angular Core: 4.1.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
Node: 6.11.0
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: In your app.module,ts enter ApiService to providers. I think that is causing the issue. MarketItemsApi is also missing from the providers array.

Comment: I added both ApiService and MarketItemsApi to my app.module's providers array, but still get the same error. I thought if I imported the ApiModule to my AppModule that MarketItemsApi would be available to my component (so long as I provided it in the component's array) since the component is contained within its own feature module which in turn is imported by a TabsModule and finally that is imported into AppModule. Please correct me if that is wrong.

Comment: Please, do not provide the services in the `app.module`, but in the module in which they are declared. Otherwise you will have to provide them every time you use the module

Comment: I updated the code to only provide the services needed at the feature module level, yet receive the same error